# CSS: navbar sizing IE, chrome

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have noticed difference between chrome, IE and mozilla. I am trying to make my navigation bar look the same (fit in one line), but it does not work in IE and mozilla.

This is how it looks on mozilla and IE: http://puu.sh/o8zxM/d44055d82c.png
This is how it looks on Chrome: http://puu.sh/o8zBw/a06f0437d1.png

CSS code for it:

```
#nav3 {
margin-top: 12px;
background-color: #F4F4F4;
overflow: hidden;
font-size: 14px;
}

#nav3 ul {
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: table;
letter-spacing: -1em;
}

#nav3 ul .li3 {
display: inline-table;
list-style-type: none;
letter-spacing: normal;
}

.li3 a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
padding-top: 44px;
padding-bottom: 44px;
color: #000;
border: black solid 1px;
}

#beds {
padding-left: 40px;
padding-right: 40px;
}

#chairs {
padding-left: 45px;
padding-right: 45px;
}

#desks {
padding-left: 38px;
padding-right: 38px;
}

#mirrors {
padding-left: 32px;
padding-right: 32px;
}

#book {
padding-left: 11px;
padding-right: 11px;
}

#tables {
padding-left: 52px;
padding-right: 52px;
}

#dress {
padding-left: 13px;
padding-right: 23px;
}

#storage {
padding-left: 40px;
padding-right: 32px;
}
```

Also I know that it is not the best case when I id every single element in navbar, but I could not find any solution so they stand in those exact positions.

I hope I was clear with my problem.

Comment: Either use `whitespace: no-wrap` with scroll or set to a percentage for the width's and padding.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith whitespace: attribute did not work.

Can u provide some sample of % for widht and paddin in navbar, please?

Comment: Yes, if you provide your HTML